# Should answers include support requirements?

Tags: discussion

In the JavaScript tag, first we went through an ES5 phase where some authors felt compelled to point out that `forEach` was not available in IE8, and would point to support tables and polyfills and even provide alternative versions of their code. Or, if the author did not, then eager-beaver commenters would step in and point out that this answer would not work in prehistoric browsers.

Now we have *déjà vu* all over again with ES6 and its dozens of new features, such as arrow functions, which of course are supported just fine in any self-respecting ES6 toolchain, but not in certain browsers.

Is it recommended, or optional, or frowned on, for authors to add disclaimers about support of such features? If they don't, is it considered a Good Thing for commenters to weigh in with their opinion that the answer should have included the disclaimer, which often gives rise to distracting comment threads as others opine on the pros and cons of disclaimers? I have also seen cases where people edit the answer itself to include the disclaimer; is this a Good Thing?

Comment: There has to be a balance somewhere. For example, in the year 2016, chances are good that the only people who care anymore whether IE5 supports the W3C box model or IE6 supports CSS2 selectors are those who know well enough about those browsers that they shouldn't even have to ask in the first place.

Comment: Also, I stopped posting answers alluding to future standards because having to include a disclaimer that "this isn't implemented anywhere or widely yet so don't bother using it in production" *even when it's patently obvious* gets old really quickly, and besides such answers aren't terribly useful to *today's* developers - they would only be useful in the future, so the best thing to do in such cases would be to wait.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, but there is a spectrum of "future", ranging from `forEach` to arrow functions to `await`. FWIW, one of my more up-voted answers is about something that's entirely in the future, the ["type-or-unit" parameter to CSS `attr`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734546/using-html-data-attribute-to-set-css-background-image-url/18431942#18431942).

Comment: [I know that feature all too well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers/8769922#8769922)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, in general authors should indicate in their answers when they use post-ES5 features.

This is not necessary when they question is already tagged [es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6), [es7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es7) or [ecmascript-next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-next), or the OP's code already contains that particular feature.

However, we can expect our readers nowadays to know about ES6, ES7 etc and that (not how) they differ from ES5. It is not necessary to include a browser/engine support table for all the particular features you are using, like saying "*`slice` does not work for this case in IE<9*". All you need to do is say "*Using ES6, you can…*".
Our users are expected to know how and where they can look up support of language features in implementations they care about, and how to use appropriate tooling for environments where it's not supported. Or even if they don't know, that is a separate question and should not concern your answer.
A small exception to the rule might be the use of features that cannot be transpiled to or polyfilled in ES5. If you do such, it's usually worth to point this out (and usually you discuss this anyway).

Comment: Good point about the tagging. I'd neglected to mention that.

Answer (score 16):

**Yes**, this is a *useful* bit of information to have in an answer, assuming that there are still a significant number of people who are forced to deal with the older technologies.

As such, people who post answers should include this information if they (a) are aware of it, and (b) think of it when they are composing the answer.

Better yet, if you can link to some type of official documentation that, among other things, contains supported version information, then you should just do that and leave the nitty-gritty details out of the answer altogether. For example, if you link to the documentation for a particular API function, it will generally tell you since what version that API was supported. For CSS, there are nice third-party websites that have assembled support/compatibility matrices, such as [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/). caniuse also has some JS information, and most JavaScript entries on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) have reasonable support/compatibility info as well.

**But no**, people should not leave *comments* on the answer about this type of thing. Those are just noise, and inevitably lead to unwanted "discussion". No one should have to read all the comments just to see what "disclaimers" should have been in the answer proper. If it is appropriate for an answer to contain a support disclaimer, then that information should just be edited directly into the answer (in a very non-intrusive way) without bothering anyone.

If you do not have edit privileges, you should avoid suggesting an edit of this nature (unless you are simultaneously making other changes that substantially improve the quality of the answer). You should also avoid leaving a noisy comment unless it is a particularly egregious/obvious case. Leave this kind of maintenance for the users with full editing privileges. I posit that these are the users who have demonstrated they can be trusted to determine when this type of support information is appropriate and when it is not.

Comment: *"As such, people who post answers should include this information if they (a) are aware of it, and (b) think of it when they are composing the answer."* And they *should* get in the habit of thinking of it. Posting an [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) answer today and not flagging up that it won't work on a huge number of people's devices without a shim is not useful. It doesn't have to be intrusive. It does need to be there. Perhaps link this answer when editing it in for them. :-)

Comment: Well, sure, but it's not always that clear cut. I was thinking of the case where you post an answer that depends on C++11 features. There are still a non-trivial number of users stuck on C++03 compilers (or with only partial C++11 implementations), but it might honestly slip your mind that something required C++11 if you have the luxury of working only with the latest stuff.

Comment: Yeah, and fair enough.

Comment: Disagree with the reasoning about adding. Looks like a patented Catch 22.

Comment: @ivan What is the catch 22?

Comment: @CodyGray: [Wiki: A paradoxical situation from which an individual cannot escape because of contradictory rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic))

Comment: @draka Hmm yeah, I know quite well what a catch-22 is. I'm asking where ivan_pozdeev sees the catch-22 in my answer, because I don't see it.

Comment: I don't see the harm in adding a comment with the support information if you don't have the required rep to edit it in.  The answer's author is then free to incorporate that information and it still bypasses the edit review cycle.

Comment: There is no harm on a small scale, @Gus, so in cases where you think it is absolutely essential to point out, you should do it. But it does not scale well if you are a low-rep user in the JavaScript tag and you go around leaving comments on *every* answer (or even 60% of them). It is a judgment call, like everything; the point I'm making in my answer is that I do not want to encourage an official policy of "leave a comment".